# Layout Rendering issue android studio 0.8.0

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-studio, render

I had a working project in eclipse. I made a new project in android studio and remade the same project here by copy pasting the code(I have too much problems with importing, so I preffered to make the project afresh). I loved everything in android studio except the rendering issue withe the main activity xml file. I have copy pasted the xml file as such from the eclipse project where it was working perfect. But in android studio it is showing rendering error. In fact android studio is taking none of the resources i have in the drawable/dimen/string/color, nothing to show and it is always showing this error message:

```
NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts
```

I have gone through the entire thing and everything is well. The program is even running smoothly with the screens perfectly as it is. I just can't use the interface builder. What can be the issue here? How can I resolve it? Do I need to import something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok.. It seems like the same fix as of eclipse works on android studio as well. I had previously tried rebuilding the project, cleaning and building again and everything, but closing android studio and restarting solved the problem. It is just that after restarting android studio, you may have to wait for some time until the sync is finished, but it is working perfectly well now.